# Error when trying to cast numpy.ndarray to set. (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write an algorithm that gets a sequence of numbers and check in a 1-9 grid for all the combinations of three numbers in a row that do not exists in the input sequence.

###### **For example:**

The input is **'372003'**.

###### **The grid is two dimensional array like this:**

**[1, 2, 3]

[4, 5, 6]

[7, 8, 9]**

The output shuold be this:
**[1, 5, 9],

[4, 5, 6]**
because there is the middle row and left to right diagonal line that all the numbers do not exists in the input sequence:

#### Note: I dont care to change the type/structure of the grid or the way that the sequence is stored, I just want the goal of the input and the output to be the same. I can change everything if it is easier that way.

##### **this is what I have tried: (I don't know if the algorithm is working)**

```
import numpy as np

# example array
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

# example sequence of digits
seq = '372003'

# convert sequence to set of digits
seq_set = set(int(d) for d in seq)

# iterate over all rows, columns, and diagonals
for axis in range(-2, 1):
    for i in range(3):
        # extract elements from current row/column/diagonal
        elements = arr.take([i, i+1, i+2], axis=axis, mode='wrap')
        # check if all elements are not in seq_set
        if not set(elements).intersection(seq_set):
            print(elements)
```

But I get this error when running this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/tester.py", line 18, in <module>
    if not set(elements).intersection(seq_set):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: The `TypeError` comes about because the array `elements` is 2D, whereas a set is a linear sequence ("1D"). Replace `set(elements)` with `set(elements.flat)`.